# How do I install this PIP package from Github?

Tags: python, github

I am basically trying to access crunchbase data through their REST API using python. There is a package available on github that gives me the following documentation. How do I get this "package" ?

The CrunchBase API provides a RESTful interface to the data found on CrunchBase. The response is in JSON format.

#### Register

Follow the steps below to start using the CrunchBase API:

Sign Up
Login & get API key
Browse the documentation.

#### Setup

```
pip install git+git://github.com/anglinb/python-crunchbase**
```

#### Up & Running

Import Crunchbase then intialize the Crunchbase object with your api key.

git+git://github.com/anglinb/python-crunchbase

Comment: This link might help you out; it's a little less terse: https://data.crunchbase.com/docs/using-the-api Otherwise it's not really clear where you're stuck - the instructions on PyPI are pretty straightforward assuming you already understand how to use pip and APIs.

Comment: `How do I get this "package" ?`, run the command `pip install git+git://github.com/anglinb/python-crunchbase`

Comment: I don't understand how to use pip..

Comment: @user8378867 well there's your problem :) Using it is the easy part (you just type on the command prompt `pip install [package name]`) but making sure you have it installed correctly and configured trips a lot of new Python users up. Depending on your platform and Python version (2.x or 3.x) you'll need different instructions but here's a start for Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: :-) yes complete newbie here. Am barely a part-time developer, I just need some venture deal info from crunchbase and I want to automate it. I wrote my own python code to get the info I need from crunchbase and parsing the JSON object was so slow!! Then I came across this package on github and it was coded so much better - I just wanted to give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

`pip install git+https://github.com/anglinb/python-crunchbase.git`

You are missing the **https**

Update: make sure you have **git** installed on your system.

Comment: This relies on the setup.py, maybe it's broken ?

Comment: it says " the system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q https:..github.com/anglinb/python-crunchbase.git. Cannot find command 'git'

Comment: You have to install git, that's your issue

Comment: Thank you! Let me see how I can install git

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your requirements.txt file.

```
git+https://github.com/user_name/project_name.git
```

=========

Ideally `requirements.txt` or `reqs.txt` will exist in your project's root folder. This file is where all the python libraries' names will be stored along with precise version number.

Here is great deal of information with easy examples related to this topic

https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html

Comment: Thank you!! Could you please let me know where the requirements.txt resides?

Comment: @user8378867 Updated the answer.

Comment: Alright some progress finally. Got git, but now I face another error not directly related to pip but perhaps with the package itself?                                          It says "downloading ..81kb/                                                                                          Cannot unpack file c:\<path>\pip-build